# How to display an href vertically in the middle with the same underlining as the picture?

Tags: html, css, href

[image]

I want to display the href similar to this picture (home, About, Portofolio...) vertically, in the middle and same alignment.

**HTML Code:**

```
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA" leftmargin=150px topmargin=20px link="blue" vlink="purple" hlink="darkpink"> 
 <a href="SiteMap.html" > Home </a> &nbsp; 
 <a href="About.html" > About </a> &nbsp; 
 <a href="Portfolio.html" >Portfolio</a> &nbsp; 
 <a href="Services.html" >Services </a> &nbsp; 
 <a href="info.html" >Contact </a> <br> <br> <br>
```

Comment: can you show us what you have done? any html/css

Comment: <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA"  leftmargin=150px
topmargin=20px link="blue"
vlink="purple" hlink="darkpink">                                                                     <a href="SiteMap.html" > Home  </a> &nbsp;
 <a href="About.html" > About </a> &nbsp;
 <a href="Portfolio.html" >Portfolio</a> &nbsp;
 <a href="Services.html" >Services </a> &nbsp;
 <a href="info.html" >Contact </a> 
 <br> <br> <br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

I am not sure what you want in href static or hover:

If href default:

```
li a {
border-bottom: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

if href hover:

```
li a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

you can use border is dotted or dashed looking for your site.

Comment: How can I remove the underline that already exists by default?

Comment: replease this and you can try li a:hover { text-decoration: none;}

Comment: Thank you a lot it was really helpful!